Does Hogwarts Legacy have an in-game FPS Counter?
I'd like to see how much FPS (frames per second) I get in the game, does Hogwarts Legacy have a setting somewhere to enable an in-game FPS Counter?

No, it doesn't have but if you have purchased the game on Steam, you can enable the Steam overlay FPS counter:

Go to Steam settings.
Go to the "In-Game" tab.
Under "In-game FPS counter," select the position where you want the
FPS counter to appear.


